# React Native - Interactive initial page

Tags: react-native

I'm interested in having a view which initially loads with my React Native app that essentially has nested components in it. These components will give visual queues to the user as to what state the app is in, eg: still loading data from the server, etc. Basically, it's not just a static splash screen. I might also add some kind of spinner/progress bar, eg: other animated components.

There are solutions out there for static splash screens that initially show while your app loads into memory, but I need to be able to load an initial component, and then remove it when the application's data is ready to go. Is there a convention/pattern to follow in order to achieve this? Is there a way to mount a component, then remove it when it's no longer necessary allowing the rest of the app to be displayed? What's a best practice for this using React Native?

Comment: rather than having pages wouldn't it be better if the initial component that is loaded is very lightweight there is a google I/O 16 talk in which they show one such demo using react, angular 2 , ember etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I used to do:

1. Use [`<Modal />`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal.html) to provide your initial, interactive page. It will blocks the screen, with semi-transparent background; If you like it to be full width, just use `flex: 1` within the `<View />` inside `<Modal />`.
2. Use global object / queue for loading status information. My choice is [rxjs](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS), then your initial page can just listen to this one source of truth, suggest a [BehaviorSubject](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/subjects/BehaviorSubject.html). So you can subscribe on it for something like:

   ```js
   ...
   { tag: 'FetchRemoteData', progress: 10 }
   { tag: 'LoadingComponent', progress: 5 }
   { tag: 'FetchRemoteData', progress: 20 }
   ...
   ```

Read it until match your "load complete" conditions, then close the model.

To make it clear with code.

### app.js

```js
render() {
    return (
        <View>
            <InitialBlockingPage />
            <YourMainApp />
        </View>
    );
}
```

### initial-blocking-page.js

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        visible: true
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    globalQueue.subscribe( () => {
        /// pseudo code: until fully loaded
        if (fullloaded) this.setState({visible: false});
    });
}

render() {
    return (
        <Modal visible={this.state.visible}>
            <SplashScreenWithData />
        </Modal>
    );
}
```